# Download file from url sent in request to django app

Tags: python, django

In my django app I am receiving a request with JSON like this:

```
{    
  "item1": false,
  "item2": false,
  "item3": "value",
  "url": "http://downloadlink.example.net"
}
```

I have to save all data except url by which I just need to download text file and save it on server. How can I do the download part?

Code in view:

```
class Collect(View):
@csrf_exempt
def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    return super(Collect, self).dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)

def post(self, request):
    data = json.loads(request.body.decode())
    try:
        item1 = data["item1"]
        item2 = data["item2"]
        item3 = data["item3"]
        url = data["url"]
        new_row = ModelName(
            item1=item1,
            item2=item2,
            item3=item3,
        )
        new_row.save()
    except Error:
        return HttpResponse("Unable to save")

    return HttpResponse("Saved")
```

Comment: Have a look at http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So basically you can use [urllib](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib.html) library and specifically its [urlretrieve](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib.html?highlight=urlretrieve#urllib.urlretrieve) function to save the file in the temp folder locally first, then you can save it anywhere you want.

```
import urllib
response = urllib.urlretrieve(url)
contents = open(response[0]).read()
f = open('filename.ext','w')
f.write(contents)
f.close()
```

That is the basic example of how to save files from links. When you are saving files you should include the full path, so make sure to create a BASE_DIR constant in your settings file. You can go further and create a FileField or ImageField tables in your db, read [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.FileField) for more examples.

Answer (score 0):

I think best practice solution is using [celery](http://celeryproject.org) because requesting another server while user is waiting is inappropriate and delays the user and sometimes it may take little long for bigger files. You can read the [docs](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/django/first-steps-with-django.html) for more. I highly recommend it!